# XML Transformation - Include element from "subnode" in parent as attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I'm trying to convert an XML file through XSLT.
The Output XML needs to contain the elements as attributes.

My input file looks like this:

```html
<queryResponse>
 <entity>
  <DevicesDTO>
    <name>value</name>
    <type>value</type>
    <manufacturersNrs>
     <manufacturersNr>value</manufacturersNr>
    </manufacturersNrs>
  </DevicesDTO>
 </entity>
</queryResponse>
```

and my output would need to be this:

```
<Data>
 <Device name=xxx type=xxxx manufacturersNr=xxx />
</Data>
```

now so far I've been succesfull in converting my xml and getting name & type as attributes.
However manufacturersNr is included in manufacturersNr**s** and I've got no idea how to get thatone included in the node above it.

My xslt file looks like this at the moment:

```css
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="queryResponse">
    <Data>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="devicesDTO">
    <Device>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </Device>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any hints for a complete xslt newbie? 
What I have now I've pieced together from various sources so if I need to do a full re-write.. so be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `<xsl:for-each select="*">` to `<xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[not(*)]">` you have some easy fix I think.

Comment: Seems to do the trick! Any chance you can explain the logic behind this? I have some other files that have similar issues that I might be able to fix if I can understand it properly :)

Comment: Your original attempt with `select="*"` processes a child element, my suggestion processes all descendant elements (`descendant::*`) not having any child elements of their own (expressed as `descendant::*[not(*)]`) so in your case it processes `name`, `type` and `manufacturersNr` but not `manufacturersNrs` as that element has a child element.